# using echo to append to a file

Tags: bash, for-loop, syntax, echo

I have a list of file names from a directory that I got using find. The list is stored in a variable x
`x=$(find ./directory -type f -exec basename '{}' \;)`
The problem is that I'd like to put the list into a file(with each name on a new line) so that I can use `sort` on it.

I have tried a for loop but it does not seem to work

```
for var in $x:
echo $var\n >> files.txt
```

Ideally, this would append every file name to the files.txt with each on a new line.

Comment: `for var in $x:` is Python syntax, not shell syntax. You might be thinking `for var in $x; do`, but that's buggy too.

Comment: When it is invoked _without `-n`_, `echo` appends a new line. Your code produces empty lines between the data lines.

Comment: Are you using GNU find? If so, it can do the work of `basename` internally; see the `-printf` action in `man find`.

Comment: `find ./directory -type f -printf '%P\n' >>files.txt` -- no `for` loop, no `basename`, no `echo`.

Comment: For future understanding, see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and [UsingFind](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind). _In particular_ read the _Actions in Bulk_ section.

Comment: On Linux there is usually more than one way to skin a cat, but some of them are wrong or used incorrectly. Take a look at the [Bash pitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) page to find out why all three lines of code that you posted may produce unexpected outcome in some circumstances.

Comment: See `help for` and please add a valid shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to your script, then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement all the recommendations made there.

Comment: To correct myself: For basename you want `-printf '%f\n'`, not `-printf '%P\n'` (which strips only `./directory`, not the whole path).